# Omitting a preposition in relative clauses

Tags: prepositions, word-order, relative-clauses

Which of those sentences sound OK?

> a) On the picture, we can see the environment tigers live.
>
> b) On the picture, we can see the environment in which tigers live.
>
> c) On the picture, we can see the environment tigers live in.

I don't really understand why so many people fight against prepositions at the ends of the sentences considering I hear that extremely often in everyday speech.

Comment: Without the preposition, **live** becomes transitive, which it is not, in this context: tigers do not live an environment.  They can inhabit an environment, but that verb sneaks the **in** in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would say **in the picture** rather than **on**.  We might also say **this** instead of **the**, but this is difficult to judge without context.

Otherwise, **b** and **c** are both correct, but **b** is very formal, maybe even a little stilted.  **C** is perfect for everyday speech, but in writing I would tend to add the conjunction **that** before the word **tigers**.

The following would also be correct:

- We can see the environment where tigers live.
- We can see the environment inhabited by tigers.
- We can see the environment tigers inhabit.

However, **a** is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much, seems like our teacher just got it wrong.

Comment: +1 but ***very* formal** is a bit of an overstatement, IMO.